# AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'LookupTensor'

Tags: tensorflow, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-ml

**I am trying to run a training job in Google Cloud using Tensorflow . I tried to run the training using by running the following command.**

```
gcloud ml-engine jobs submit training training_1 \
--job-dir=gs://object-detection-bucket-test/train \
--packages dist/object_detection-0.1.tar.gz,slim/dist/slim-0.1.tar.gz \
--module-name object_detection.train \
--region us-central1 \
--config object_detection/samples/cloud/cloud.yml \
--runtime-version=1.2 \
-- \
--train_dir=gs://object-detection-bucket-test/train \
--pipeline_config_path=gs://object-detection-bucket-test/data/ssd_mobilenet_v1_coco.config
```

**But When I run a job, I am getting the following error. Any idea why?**

The replica master 0 exited with a non-zero status of 1. Termination reason: Error. Traceback (most recent call last): File "/usr/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 174, in _run_module_as_main "main", fname, loader, pkg_name) File "/usr/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 72, in _run_code exec code in run_globals File "/root/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/object_detection/train.py", line 167, in tf.app.run() File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/platform/app.py", line 48, in run _sys.exit(main(_sys.argv[:1] + flags_passthrough)) File "/root/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/object_detection/train.py", line 163, in main worker_job_name, is_chief, FLAGS.train_dir) File "/root/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/object_detection/trainer.py", line 235, in train train_config.prefetch_queue_capacity, data_augmentation_options) File "/root/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/object_detection/trainer.py", line 59, in create_input_queue tensor_dict = create_tensor_dict_fn() File "/root/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/object_detection/train.py", line 120, in get_next dataset_builder.build(config)).get_next() File "/root/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/object_detection/builders/dataset_builder.py", line 138, in build label_map_proto_file=label_map_proto_file) File "/root/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/object_detection/data_decoders/tf_example_decoder.py", line 210, in init slim_example_decoder.LookupTensor( AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'LookupTensor' The replica worker 0 exited with a non-zero status of 1. Termination reason: Error. Traceback (most recent call last): File "/usr/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 174, in _run_module_as_main "main", fname, loader, pkg_name) File "/usr/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 72, in _run_code exec code in run_globals File "/root/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/object_detection/train.py", line 167, in tf.app.run() File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/platform/app.py", line 48, in run _sys.exit(main(_sys.argv[:1] + flags_passthrough)) File "/root/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/object_detection/train.py", line 163, in main worker_job_name, is_chief, FLAGS.train_dir) File "/root/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/object_detection/trainer.py", line 235, in train train_config.prefetch_queue_capacity, data_augmentation_options) File "/root/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/object_detection/trainer.py", line 59, in create_input_queue tensor_dict = create_tensor_dict_fn() File "/root/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/object_detection/train.py", line 120, in get_next dataset_builder.build(config)).get_next() File "/root/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/object_detection/builders/dataset_builder.py", line 138, in build label_map_proto_file=label_map_proto_file) File "/root/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/object_detection/data_decoders/tf_example_decoder.py", line 210, in init slim_example_decoder.LookupTensor( AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'LookupTensor' The replica worker 1 exited with a non-zero status of 1. Termination reason: Error. Traceback (most recent call last): File "/usr/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 174, in _run_module_as_main "main", fname, loader, pkg_name) File "/usr/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 72, in _run_code exec code in run_globals File "/root/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/object_detection/train.py", line 167, in tf.app.run() File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/platform/app.py", line 48, in run _sys.exit(main(_sys.argv[:1] + flags_passthrough)) File "/root/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/object_detection/train.py", line 163, in main worker_job_name, is_chief, FLAGS.train_dir) File "/root/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/object_detection/trainer.py", line 235, in train train_config.prefetch_queue_capacity, data_augmentation_options) File "/root/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/object_detection/trainer.py", line 59, in create_input_queue tensor_dict = create_tensor_dict_fn() File "/root/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/object_detection/train.py", line 120, in get_next dataset_builder.build(config)).get_next() File "/root/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/object_detection/builders/dataset_builder.py", line 138, in build label_map_proto_file=label_map_proto_file) File "/root/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/object_detection/data_decoders/tf_example_decoder.py", line 210, in init slim_example_decoder.LookupTensor( AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'LookupTensor' The replica worker 2 exited with a non-zero status of 1. Termination reason: Error. Traceback (most recent call last): File "/usr/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 174, in _run_module_as_main "main", fname, loader, pkg_name) File "/usr/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 72, in _run_code exec code in run_globals File "/root/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/object_detection/train.py", line 167, in tf.app.run() File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/platform/app.py", line 48, in run _sys.exit(main(_sys.argv[:1] + flags_passthrough)) File "/root/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/object_detection/train.py", line 163, in main worker_job_name, is_chief, FLAGS.train_dir) File "/root/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/object_detection/trainer.py", line 235, in train train_config.prefetch_queue_capacity, data_augmentation_options) File "/root/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/object_detection/trainer.py", line 59, in create_input_queue tensor_dict = create_tensor_dict_fn() File "/root/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/object_detection/train.py", line 120, in get_next dataset_builder.build(config)).get_next() File "/root/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/object_detection/builders/dataset_builder.py", line 138, in build label_map_proto_file=label_map_proto_file) File "/root/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/object_detection/data_decoders/tf_example_decoder.py", line 210, in init slim_example_decoder.LookupTensor( AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'LookupTensor' The replica worker 3 exited with a non-zero status of 1. Termination reason: Error. Traceback (most recent call last): File "/usr/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 174, in _run_module_as_main "main", fname, loader, pkg_name) File "/usr/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 72, in _run_code exec code in run_globals File "/root/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/object_detection/train.py", line 167, in tf.app.run() File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/platform/app.py", line 48, in run _sys.exit(main(_sys.argv[:1] + flags_passthrough)) File "/root/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/object_detection/train.py", line 163, in main worker_job_name, is_chief, FLAGS.train_dir) File "/root/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/object_detection/trainer.py", line 235, in train train_config.prefetch_queue_capacity, data_augmentation_options) File "/root/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/object_detection/trainer.py", line 59, in create_input_queue tensor_dict = create_tensor_dict_fn() File "/root/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/object_detection/train.py", line 120, in get_next dataset_builder.build(config)).get_next() File "/root/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/object_detection/builders/dataset_builder.py", line 138, in build label_map_proto_file=label_map_proto_file) File "/root/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/object_detection/data_decoders/tf_example_decoder.py", line 210, in init slim_example_decoder.LookupTensor( AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'LookupTensor' The replica worker 4 exited with a non-zero status of 1. Termination reason: Error. Traceback (most recent call last): File "/usr/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 174, in _run_module_as_main "main", fname, loader, pkg_name) File "/usr/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 72, in _run_code exec code in run_globals File "/root/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/object_detection/train.py", line 167, in tf.app.run() File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/platform/app.py", line 48, in run _sys.exit(main(_sys.argv[:1] + flags_passthrough)) File "/root/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/object_detection/train.py", line 163, in main worker_job_name, is_chief, FLAGS.train_dir) File "/root/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/object_detection/trainer.py", line 235, in train train_config.prefetch_queue_capacity, data_augmentation_options) File "/root/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/object_detection/trainer.py", line 59, in create_input_queue tensor_dict = create_tensor_dict_fn() File "/root/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/object_detection/train.py", line 120, in get_next dataset_builder.build(config)).get_next() File "/root/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/object_detection/builders/dataset_builder.py", line 138, in build label_map_proto_file=label_map_proto_file) **File "/root/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/object_detection/data_decoders/tf_example_decoder.py", line 210, in init slim_example_decoder.LookupTensor( AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'LookupTensor'**

Comment: I am trying to reproduce the error you ran into and I haven't managed yet. Just to make sure, `packages`and `pipeline_config_path` are taken directly from [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/models), right? Also: have you tried with `runtime-version>1.2` ?

Comment: Run into the same issue when try out the pets dataset on Google Cloud follow the instruction from [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/running_pets.md)

Answer (score 0):

This was posted and eventually answered in [this](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/issues/3565) github issue. Upgrading the runtime to 1.5+ should resolve it.